# How to add include path of verilog to blackbox in chisel (3.2)

Tags: chisel

Sometimes it is needed to wrap other's verilog module to blackbox,
The module may instantiates a lot of other modules, so it seems better to include a path to blackbox,

I saw there is an `addPath` method in `HasBlackBoxPath` trait which is not in the official guide.

But I'm not getting this include behavior.
If do this:

```scala
class xxx extends BlackBox with HasBlackBoxResource with HasBlackBoxPath{
 val io = IO(new Bundle{
 ...
 })
 addResource("/xxx.v")
 addPath("/xxxx/xxx.../src/main/resources/Sim/")
}
```

It reports:
`Exception in thread "main" firrtl.transforms.BlackBoxNotFoundException: BlackBox '/xxxx/xxx.../src/main/resources/Sim' not found. Did you misspell it? Is it in src/{main,test}/resources?`

**Sim** is the folder where .v files are in.

Currently I'm just using addResource() multiple times to add resources needed, but this way I have to look into the verilog code to find out what module are used and where to find.

I tried `addResource("/path/*.v")` without any luck.

Is there a way to include a batch of verilog, or include a path ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try only using one or the other, they do not combine.
So something like

```
class xxx extends BlackBox with HasBlackBoxPath {
  val io = IO(new Bundle{
    ...
  })
addPath("/xxxx/xxx.../src/main/resources/Sim/xxx.v")
```

}

There are example usages in [chisel3 /src/test/scala/chiselTests/BlackBoxImpl.scala](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/master/src/test/scala/chiselTests/BlackBoxImpl.scala)